# Is there an easy way to find your character?

Tags: speedrunners

**Note**: This is not about *speedrunning*, but *SpeedRunners* the game.

I seem to constantly lose track of my character. I get confused and suddenly realize I'm not in control of the character I've been tracking for the last few seconds. Is there an easy way to keep track of your own character? Maybe there's a way to make other characters more transparent than your own?

Comment: Are you talking about a specific game? You have only tagged this with 'speedrunners'.

Comment: @Mondrianaire [SpeedRunners](http://store.steampowered.com/app/207140/)

Comment: Speedrunners is the name of the game, in fact (and it's pretty great from what I hear).

Comment: @Mondrianaire in arquade the tag is the game name ;) which leads to [awesomesauce titles](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/821/58982)

Comment: @Braiam "Arquade"? I do not know of that place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the options menu, you can select a player indicator to be shown over your character's head. Only works in online multiplayer or playing against bots though.

Comment: I thought the blue arrow was automatic.